# LongToByte and LongFromByte

Tags: c#, cross-platform, arrays, long-integer, endianness

I have the two functions shown below which I built for serialisation of long and byte[] values.

```
    public static byte[] LongToByte(long Value)
    {
        byte[] Output = new byte[8];
        Output[0] = (byte)Value;
        Output[1] = (byte)(Value >> 8);
        Output[2] = (byte)(Value >> 16);
        Output[3] = (byte)(Value >> 24);
        Output[4] = (byte)(Value >> 32);
        Output[5] = (byte)(Value >> 40);
        Output[6] = (byte)(Value >> 48);
        Output[7] = (byte)(Value >> 56);
        return Output;
    }

    public static long LongFromByte(byte[] Value)
    {
        long Output = Value[0];
        Output += ((long)Value[1] << 8);
        Output += ((long)Value[2] << 16);
        Output += ((long)Value[3] << 24);
        Output += ((long)Value[4] << 32);
        Output += ((long)Value[5] << 40);
        Output += ((long)Value[6] << 48);
        Output += ((long)Value[7] << 56);
        return Output;
    }
```

Will using the above methods ensure endianness remains the same across any platform which is using them.

Or will the result of either or change based on the endianness of the system processing the code?

Thanking all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will because you're extracting each byte individually and storing it in the array. So 'Output[0]', for example, is always the lowest 8 bits of the number you're converting. If you then write the array (to a disk file or across some transport), the bytes will always be in the order that you specified.

Alternately, you might consider using the technique described in the remarks section of the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.BitConverter.aspx) class documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid doing custom binary conversion since the default one is pretty good and have some optimizations.

I suggest you check the system endianess using:

```
var isLittleEndian = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
```

And use the custom conversion only when the current endianess is not ok (or you can just reverse the bytes using Array.Reverse(bytes))

If performance is a must (really paranoid about it), you can implement either a custom reverse bytes algorithm (using [lookup tables](http://jasonf-blog.blogspot.com/2006/08/hanselmans-endianess-converter.html) or [swapping bits](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FlipTheEndiannessOfALongInC.aspx), implement a unsafe code that convert bytes to long in the reverse order (look at [BitConverter source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/BitConverter@cs/1/BitConverter@cs)) or just improve your current code using bitwise operators.

Edit: I examined the IL code of your custom serializer (using [Telerik Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx for better convenience) and found that the cast from long to byte is made using the conv.u1 instruction.

According [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_u1.aspx) :

> If overflow occurs converting one integer type to another, the high order bits are truncated.

Considering this, your code does produce the same output in big endian systems.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your information. Although you didn't answer my initial question. You do raise a valid point for performance. I found on average that bitconvertor was 0.0052 seconds quicker over a million iterations when endianness was correct. While if bitconvertor required to have the array reversed. My method was 0.0312 seconds faster then bitconvertor.

I believe I am better off using my custom method as there is no chance endianness will have to be processed?

Comment: @MatthewDunn: Did you run your tests in Release mode without the debugger attached? (That is, run from the command line or by pressing Ctrl+F5 in the IDE.) If the debugger is attached, even in release mode, your timings will be completely unreliable.

Comment: @MatthewDunn if you are a performance freak, your code performance can be improved. I edited my answer to point some suggestions but, unless your app is very performance critical it's unecessary IMO.

Comment: @MatthewDunn yes I omitted the direct answer to your question because I was unsure about the cast from long to byte. I did some investigation and updated the answer for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Hello, My tests were in release mode using long types to capture start and finish times from System.DateTime.Now.Ticks. I then used TimeSpan to provide the TotalSeconds. My samples are averaged by three runs.

Comment: @MatthewDunn `DateTime.Now` is very poor for doing performance measurements, it often only has [down to 16ms of resolution](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021111.asp). So your numbers really are `0.0052 ± .032` and `0.0312 ± 0.032` seconds. You don't even get outside of the experimental error in your results comparing the two. Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) and let us know if the results are different.

Comment: Also how much time have you put in to this "Optimization". If you have worked on this for a hour (and your numbers where accurate) you would need to call your function 692,307 times before you even started to get dividends on your "Time saving".

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I would not put the performance optimization in this terms but 30 ms over a million executions is hardly a performance problem, unless this method is called an insane number of times and the system have a huge workload.

Comment: The difference is clear when using stopwatch instead of now.ticks. My routines are around twice as slow as bitconvertor. Thanks for the heads up on that one...